# rsvg-convert rasterizing filtered elements

Tags: svg

It seems that, when using rsvg-convert to render SVG files to PDF, elements that are affected by filter effects (such as blur) get rendered as raster images. (How) can I control the resolution of these rasters?

The -p and -d flags have no apparent effect, and neither does it seem to be affected by the user coordinate system (i.e, viewBox attribute).

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I'm not familiar with that tool. However, have you perhaps tried using Inkscape for this? You can specify the resolution for rendering SVG filters when using Save As for exporting a PDF. In the Portable Document Format dialog which pops up, there's an option for changing the rasterization resolution.

Comment: @BillyKerr Ah, interesting. I’d prefer a command-line solution, but if nothing else comes up, that will certainly do as a stop-gap measure until I (or someone else) get around to reading the librsvg sources to figure out what is going on. :)

Comment: You can use Inkscape with the command-line, however I'm no expert at using Inkscape  in this way, and I'm not really sure if it would be possible for this particular use case. Might be worth looking into though.